# Copying list to another list and adding static value in java

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have list 'abc'contains elements. I want to have a new list 'cde' in which first element is '123' and then has to add all elements of abc .How to achieve this.I am beginner to coding

```
 private List<object> abc;

 private List<object> cde;

cde={123 ,//elements of abc list}
```

Comment: The Javadoc is usually a good place to start looking if some functionality is already available. In your case, have a look at the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) Javadoc - especially, check out [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) which looks like it is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the following lines should do it:

```java
List<Integer> abc = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> cde = new ArrayList<>();

cde.add(123); // Adds 123 to your list
cde.addAll(abc); // Adds abc content at the end of list cde
```

You would need to change `cde.add(123);` to `cde.add(0, 123);` if your `cde` list is not empty and you want to place `123` as its first element.

Comment: My bad, I mixed the list variable name.

Comment: In my code that is true because the `cde` list is in fact empty. Not sure about OP's code. But thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: True, I forgot about that detail ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

[Edit: wrong use of static method Collections.addAll(...) removed]

Comment: Yeah, I got slightly confused here, my apologies. João's answer is what my acual code looks like as well.